# System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity and WinForms Authentication

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, windows-authentication

I'd like to utilize the Windows Authentication Model for authenticating users that use my C# 3.5 WinForms application:

1. The user that has logged on Windows is automatically logged in to my application.
2. If the user wants to log in explicitely, his user name and password should be checked by Windows, or even better, prompted by Windows with a standard Windows Dialog. The outcome should be another `WindowsIdentity` object.

The first was very easy to solve long time ago: I read the

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

Just to make sure, I check for the

```
if (identity.IsAuthenticated) { ... }
```

For the second case I've found some API calls in other SO Q&A's, but I'm pretty sure **there must be a managed way for that, am I wrong?**

Further I wonder whether my approach for 1. is save and appropriate. Thanks for your feedback!

**Update:** According to Ivan, I have to use the P/Invoke approach. This is basically alright, but then I still need a way to retrieve a `WindowsIdentity` object for that certain user, which has its `IsAuthenticated` property set to true. The P/Invoke call in itself doesn't return such an object. **How can this be done?**

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do the 2nd thing.  Do you want the user to run as a different user than the one they are logged in as?

Comment: @giltanis: Yes, I wanted the user to be able to authenticate by user name and password if he wants to use a different account than the one currently logged in to Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain about this but it looks like you want to use the [WindowsIdentity Ctor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85yh2h4a.aspx) that takes an IntPtr. To get the parameter that is passed into this constructor you can PInvoke the Win32 API LogonUser() function.  This will give you a WindowsIdentity for this user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no managed way of doing this, you have to do pinvoke (api call) as you said. Approach #1 is totaly ok ... trust microsoft :)